# Recommended books and articles on the origin and evolution of sexual reproduction?

Tags: evolution, literature, sexual-reproduction

I'm interested in learning about the origin and evolution of life on Earth. In particular, one topic that puzzles me a lot as a layman is the evolution of sexual reproduction, since the DNA mutations have to be such that they affect both female and male in a coordinated way so that their reproductive organs match with each other in order to make the sexual reproduction viable. Would you guys kindly recommend me high quality books and peer-reviewed articles on the matter that hopefully can clear these questions out? Thanks in advance.